# How do I optimize array access in python?

Tags: python

running `time python my.py` gets me 1.35s with the code below. Writing `import py_compile`, `py_compile.compile('my.py', optimize=2)` and running the file using `time python __pycache__/my.cpython-310.opt-2.pyc` gets me the same speed or slower. What can I do to speed this up?

```
import array
a = array.array('B')
for i in range(0, 1024*1024*10):
    a.append(i & 255)
print(str(len(a)))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible options:

```
import timeit


def array():
    import array
    a = array.array('B')
    for i in range(0, 1024 * 1024 * 10):
        a.append(i & 255)
    print(str(len(a)))


def list_comprehension():
    a = [i & 255 for i in range(0, 1024 * 1024 * 10)]
    print(str(len(a)))


def numpy_array():
    import numpy as np
    a = np.arange(0, 1024 * 1024 * 10, dtype=np.uint8) & 255
    print(str(len(a)))


def numpy_array_repeat():
    import numpy as np
    a = np.tile(np.arange(0, 256, dtype=np.uint8), 4 * 1024 * 10 )
    print(str(len(a)))


print("array", timeit.timeit(array, number=5))
print("list_comprehension", timeit.timeit(list_comprehension, number=5))
print("numpy_array", timeit.timeit(numpy_array, number=5))
print("numpy_array_repeat", timeit.timeit(numpy_array_repeat, number=5))
```

Comment: This fulfills my needs. I was wondering, if I wanted to do something more advance `for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {array[i] = i + 1 + (i>>5); }` can I do it somehow with numpy? But this question is just for fun I don't need anything like that

Comment: Hi Eric, the vectorized approaches tend to "read" better.  Numpy has overloaded most of the operators (including bitshift - but you can access the methods - see the documentation).

arr = np.arange(len);
arr + 1 + (arr >> 5);

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
v = array.array('B', range(256)) * 4 * 1024 * 10
```

Comment: This appears to be missing the bitwise AND.

Comment: @S3DEV it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
import array

arr = array.array('B')
length = int(1024 * 1024 * 10 / 256)
arr.extend([i for i in range(256)] * length)
print(len(arr))
```